# Using Bayesian networks to understand Expected Revenue

Tags: bayesian, bayesian-network, marketing

I'm trying to understand Bayesian Networks and am attempting to apply it to solve some problems in the world of marketing, most notably search engine marketing. I have a data on each in click to a website, the date/time, what keyword that visitor came from, how much I paid for that keyword, which ad was clicks, whether that visitor converted, and how much money was made from the conversion.

There are two parts to this puzzle, expected revenue and the probability of a lead converting given the predictors. For the moment, I am disregarding the probability of conversion as the joint probability of P(conversion) can be acquired for all relevant predictors via the DAG (directed acyclic graph) plot.

For expected revenue, we *could* assume that revenue per click is formally independent of position and time (time of day and ad position don't determine expected revenue). Based on some chi-square tests that I've run, I believe that this is a fair assumption to make. *However*, I was wondering how to go about determining the expected revenue using the Bayesian Network approach? What I mean is, how do I go about getting a good understanding of how much my expected revenue would be?